# need to add add user names to the post for later retrieval or removal

Tags: post-meta

I'm working on an unique feature, that requires that I add usernames to specific post.

In detail, user clicks button and if he is logged in his wp username is saved somewhere together with the post. User can click and remove himself from the list. There can be many users under single post like 200+.

I believe I have two options:

- 1) Create `meta_key` value pair and use 1 per user.
- 2) Create 1 `meta_key` with array value that contains all users.
- 3) I was thinking to maybe use comments system, as for that specific `post_type` I don't have comments at all. So I could just attach myself to that system, and instead of saving all comment data I would just store the `username`.

What do you think? Is there a better way?

Comment: Please don't use a tag like [tag:php]. It's about user meta data, so it should be tagged like this. And also take care about upper/lower case letters (proper english - at least this isn't chat) and proper formatting (for e.g. code stuff). You already got 14 questions and should know how things work. If not, please take some time to [read the FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). Last but not least: **Follow up with your old answers!** People take time to answer your Qs, so take the same amount of time, they invested for your for free and follow up!

Answer (score 0):

Decided going to use comments system to implement this feature.

Comment: This answer was flagged by the system/community user as "low quality". This happens to all one liners, as they won't help later users. Please take your time to describe what exactly you've done to solve the question. Thanks.